# knockoutjs - enable checkboxlist conditionally

Tags: binding, knockout.js

I am trying to build a simple form that will capture choices from the user. There is a limit to the number of choices the user can make.

Here is a fiddle with what I've done so far - http://jsfiddle.net/steam/7RSdf/13/

So far, I have managed to -

1. Bind a list of checkboxes
2. Capture choices made and bind them in a unordered list.
3. Disable the checkboxes once the user has made 3 choices.

The enable/disable of checkbox is done using this bit -

```
self.canVote = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.selectedTopics().length < 3 ;}, self);
```

My problem - I want my user to be able to revert/change his/her choice. This means, after 3 choices only ***the unchecked checkboxes need to be disabled***. The user can still uncheck from the list of choices he/she has made.

Is there a simple way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, change

```
enable: $root.user().canVote
```

To

```
enable: $element.checked || $root.user().canVote
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7RSdf/14/

Comment: Wonderful - I was looking for the `$element` bit. Thanks.